# SQL select all records only if the sum is greater than 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sum

I have the following SQL;

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyReport]
    @startdate  datetime,
    @enddate    datetime
AS
    /* Return the event plan (coming events) for a specific volunteer */
   declare @sd datetime
   declare @ed datetime

    /* Ensure that the start and end dates covert whole days */
    set @sd = convert(varchar(10),@startdate,120) + ' 00:00:00'
    set @ed = convert(varchar(10),@enddate,120) + ' 23:59:59'

    SELECT 
       E.EventID, E.EventDate, E.StartTime, E.StartLocation, E.EndTime, 
       E.EndLocation, E.Charged, E.Actual,E.ChargeRate, E.Cost, 
       E.Persons, E.Reason,
       C.ClientID, C.Address1, C.Address2,
       C.Town, C.County, C.Postcode, 
       C.InvoiceName, C.InvoiceAddress1, C.InvoiceAddress2,
       C.InvoiceTown, C.InvoiceCounty, C.InvoicePostCode,
       ISNULL(C.Surname, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(C.Forename, '') AS ClientSurnameForename
    FROM 
       vEvents E 
    INNER JOIN 
       vClients C ON E.ClientID = C.ClientID
    WHERE    
       (E.EventDate BETWEEN @sd AND @ed) 
       AND E.SchemeID = 4
    ORDER BY 
       c.Surname, c.Forename, E.EventDate, E.StartTime, E.EndTime
```

I need to sum the column E.Charged to check see if the amount for the client is greater than 0 before returning the recordset.  I have tried the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyReport]
    @startdate  datetime,
    @enddate    datetime
AS
    /* Return the event plan (coming events) for a specific volunteer */
    declare @sd datetime
    declare @ed datetime

    /* Ensure that the start and end dates covert whole days */
    set @sd = convert(varchar(10),@startdate,120) + ' 00:00:00'
    set @ed = convert(varchar(10),@enddate,120) + ' 23:59:59'

    SELECT 
        E.EventID, E.EventDate, E.StartTime, E.StartLocation, E.EndTime, 
        E.EndLocation, E.Charged, E.Actual,E.ChargeRate, E.Cost, 
        E.Persons, E.Reason,
        C.ClientID, C.Address1, C.Address2, C.Town, C.County, C.Postcode,
        C.InvoiceName, C.InvoiceAddress1, C.InvoiceAddress2, C.InvoiceTown,
        C.InvoiceCounty, C.InvoicePostCode,
        ISNULL(C.Surname, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(C.Forename, '') AS ClientSurnameForename
    FROM 
        vEvents E 
    INNER JOIN 
        vClients C ON E.ClientID = C.ClientID
    WHERE 
        vEvents.ClientID IN (SELECT vEvents.Charged 
                             FROM vEvents 
                             GROUP BY vEvents.ClientID, vEvents.charged 
                             HAVING SUM(vEvents.Charged) > 0) 
        AND (E.EventDate BETWEEN @sd AND @ed) 
        AND E.SchemeID = 4
    ORDER BY 
        c.Surname, c.Forename, E.EventDate, E.StartTime, E.EndTime
```

But I keep getting 'the multipart identifier could not be bound'.  TIA Andrew

Table Structure

```
    [vEvents](
[EventID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ClientID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ChargeID] [int] NOT NULL,
[EventDate] [datetime] NULL,
[StartTime] [datetime] NULL,
[StartLocation] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[EndTime] [datetime] NULL,
[EndLocation] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Reason] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Charged] [decimal](6, 2) NOT NULL,
[Actual] [decimal](6, 2) NOT NULL,
[Additional] [decimal](6, 2) NOT NULL,
[Done] [bit] NOT NULL,
[Verifier] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ChargeRate] [decimal](6, 4) NULL,
[TeamID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Combined] [bit] NOT NULL,
```

Its an edit list but contains the most relevant

The Client Table

```
    [vClients](
[ClientID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ManagerID] [int] NOT NULL,
[RegularID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Forename] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Surname] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Address1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Address2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Town] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[County] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[PostCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[Telephone] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[Comments] [ntext] NULL,
[ReviewDate] [datetime] NULL,
[Requirements] [int] NOT NULL,
[Status] [int] NOT NULL,
[EmergencyType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[EmergencyContact] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[EmergencyNotes] [ntext] NULL,
[EmergencyTelephone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Title] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[VolunteerID] [int] NOT NULL,
[UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
[DateOfBirth] [datetime] NULL,
[HasPushPin] [bit] NULL,
[InvoiceAddress1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[InvoiceAddress2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[InvoiceTown] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[InvoiceCounty] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[InvoicePostcode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[InvoiceName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
```

Comment: WHat table sturcture do you have?

Comment: Can you please post some sample source data and expected output?

Comment: I can see a bug at `vEvents.ClientID IN (SELECT vEvents.Charged 
                             FROM vEvents...`, the SELECT column should be vEvents.ClientID

Comment: See above for table structure

Comment: Difficult to post sample data.  But I'll have a go

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?  Note that your current subquery isn't going to work, because you're `GROUP`ing by the column you want to sum (this is what @Dan's answer points to).  I'd normally start with it as a subselect in a join, but that doesn't materially change things otherwise (and the optimizer may reduce them to the same thing).  Oh, and _especially_ in SQL Server, [don't use BETWEEN with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (or in my opinion, anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the WHERE part of your query to something like this:

```
WHERE 
    E.ClientID IN (SELECT vEvents.ClientID 
                         FROM vEvents 
                         GROUP BY vEvents.ClientID 
                         HAVING SUM(vEvents.Charged) > 0) 
    AND ...
```

Comment: No Joy still get : The multi-part identifier "vEvents.ClientID" could not be bound.

Comment: My bad - I didn't notice that you aliased the vEvents table to the name "E" in the outer query. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyReport]
    @startdate  datetime,
    @enddate    datetime
AS
    /* Return the event plan (coming events) for a specific volunteer */
    declare @sd datetime
    declare @ed datetime

    /* Ensure that the start and end dates covert whole days */
    set @sd = convert(varchar(10),@startdate,120) + ' 00:00:00'
    set @ed = convert(varchar(10),@enddate,120) + ' 23:59:59'

    SELECT 
        E.EventID, E.EventDate, E.StartTime, E.StartLocation, E.EndTime, 
        E.EndLocation, E.Charged, E.Actual,E.ChargeRate, E.Cost, 
        E.Persons, E.Reason,
        C.ClientID, C.Address1, C.Address2, C.Town, C.County, C.Postcode,
        C.InvoiceName, C.InvoiceAddress1, C.InvoiceAddress2, C.InvoiceTown,
        C.InvoiceCounty, C.InvoicePostCode,
        ISNULL(C.Surname, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(C.Forename, '') AS ClientSurnameForename
    FROM 
        vEvents E 
    INNER JOIN 
        vClients C ON E.ClientID = C.ClientID
    INNER JOIN (SELECT ClientID, SUM(Charged) ch
                FROM vEvents 
                GROUP BY ClientID
                HAVING SUM(Charged) > 0) t
      ON t.ClientID = vEvents.ClientID
    WHERE (E.EventDate BETWEEN @sd AND @ed) 
        AND E.SchemeID = 4
    ORDER BY 
        c.Surname, c.Forename, E.EventDate, E.StartTime, E.EndTime
```